# prompting integer and string input using "input" in python

Tags: python

In python can I use input() to take the input irrespective of data type.I know we cannot enter a string directly using input(). But how can I prompt a user for input without the user knowing the type of input?

Comment: What do you mean "we cannot enter a string directly using input()"?

Comment: I know we can use raw_input for the string. But I need to enter the data with the data type being preserved.

Comment: I meant we cannot enter hello but can enter 'hello'

Comment: input always gets you string. than you have to convert it to any format you want, e.g. int, float, etc.

Comment: The actual problem is: I need find the data types from the input, say I input 1 and hello. I need to print out int and string. If I use input() I cannot input just hello instead of 'hello'. If I use raw_input, 1 is taken as string. But I want it to be converted to int so that I can print int for 1

Comment: I also know that we can use isinstance() to check for a specific datatype. But I cant check every data type possible..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`input` (assuming Python 3; in Python 2 you should be using `raw_input`) always returns a string. So, what you have to do is try to convert it to various data types. When you can't convert it to one, try another. If you can't convert it to any type you try, just use the string as-is. For simple situations, I like a helper function:

```
def tryconvert(value, *types):
    for t in types:
        try:
            return t(value)
        except ValueError, TypeError:
            continue
    return value

value = tryconvert(input("Enter value: "), int, float)
```

Note that you must specify the types to try from most-exclusive to least. For example, every integer can be parsed as a float, so `float` can't come before `int` because all your `int`s would be parsed as `float`s.

Another way you can do it is using `ast.literal_eval` which converts a string containing any valid Python literal to that data type, using Python's own rules. (This lets you enter `True`, `False`, `None`, lists, tuples, and dictionaries as well as integers, floats, and complex numbes.) If this fails, you can catch the error and just use the original string as entered.

```
from ast import literal_eval
value = input("Enter value: ")
try:
    value = literal_eval(value)
except ValueError:
    pass
```

Once the string has been parsed, printing the type of the value is easy:

```
print(type(value))
```

or more succinctly:

```
print(type(value).__name__))
```